# Pandas Divide Dataframe by Another Based on Column Values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to divide a pandas dataframe by another based on the column values.
For example let's say I have:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'NAME': [ 'CA', 'CA', 'CA', 'AZ', 'AZ', 'AZ', 'TX', 'TX', 'TX'], 'NUM':[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 'VALUE': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90]})
>>> df
  NAME  NUM  VALUE
0   CA    1     10
1   CA    2     20
2   CA    3     30
3   AZ    1     40
4   AZ    2     50
5   AZ    3     60
6   TX    1     70
7   TX    2     80
8   TX    3     90
>>> states = pd.DataFrame({'NAME': ['CA', "AZ", "TX"], 'DIVISOR': [10, 5, 1]})
>>> states
  NAME  DIVISOR
0   CA       10
1   AZ        5
2   TX        1
```

For each STATE and NUM I want to divide the VALUE column in df by the divisor COLUMN of the respective state.

Which would give a result of

```
>>> result = pd.DataFrame({'NAME': [ 'CA', 'CA', 'CA', 'AZ', 'AZ', 'AZ', 'TX', 'TX', 'TX'], 'NUM':[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 'VALUE': [1, 2, 3, 8, 10, 12, 70, 80, 90]})
>>> result
  NAME  NUM  VALUE
0   CA    1      1
1   CA    2      2
2   CA    3      3
3   AZ    1      8
4   AZ    2     10
5   AZ    3     12
6   TX    1     70
7   TX    2     80
8   TX    3     90
```

Comment: The practical approach would be to join the two dataframes on the field name and then you can divide the two columns by each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use merge as well

```
result = df.merge(states,on=['NAME'])
result['NEW VALUE'] = result.VALUE/result.DIVISOR
print(result)

NAME  NUM  VALUE  NEW VALUE  DIVISOR
0   CA    1     10        1.0       10
1   CA    2     20        2.0       10
2   CA    3     30        3.0       10
3   AZ    1     40        8.0        5
4   AZ    2     50       10.0        5
5   AZ    3     60       12.0        5
6   TX    1     70       70.0        1
7   TX    2     80       80.0        1
8   TX    3     90       90.0        1
```

Answer (score 4):

Let us do `map`

```
df['NEW VALUE'] = df['VALUE'].div(df['NAME'].map(states.set_index('NAME')['DIVISOR']))
df
Out[129]: 
  NAME  NUM  VALUE  NEW VALUE
0   CA    1     10        1.0
1   CA    2     20        2.0
2   CA    3     30        3.0
3   AZ    1     40        8.0
4   AZ    2     50       10.0
5   AZ    3     60       12.0
6   TX    1     70       70.0
7   TX    2     80       80.0
8   TX    3     90       90.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel like there must be a more eloquent way to accomplish what you are looking for, but this is the rout that I usually take.

```
myresult = df.copy()
for i in range(len(df['NAME'])):
    for j in range(len(states['NAME'])):
        if  df['NAME'][i] == states['NAME'][j]:
            myresult['VALUE'][i] = df['VALUE'][i]/states['DIVISOR'][j]
    
myresult.head()

Out[10]>>
  NAME  NUM VALUE
0   CA  1   1
1   CA  2   2
2   CA  3   3
3   AZ  1   8
4   AZ  2   10
```

This is a very brute force method. You start by looping through each value in the data frame `df`, then you loop through each element in the data frame `states`. Then for each comparison, you look to see if the `NAME` columns match. If they do, you do the `VALUE` / `DIVISOR`.

You will get a warring for using the `.copy()` method